# Convert promise chain to async await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I want to convert promise in to async await but I'm not able to find the right way to do it to make sure every call works.

I'm trying to remove all the data related to a user from mongodb collections and s3 bucket on delete of the user.

This code was written by someone else and I'm trying to refactor it in a more readable and efficient state.

```js
"use strict";

const deleteById = require("./logic/deleteById");
const deleteFootPrint = require("./logic/deleteFootPrint");
const fileUpload = require("../../helpers/fileUpload");
const deleteDocuments = require("./logic/deleteDocuments");
const deleteAssignments = require("./logic/deleteAssignments");
const deleteQueries = require("./logic/deleteQueries");
const deleteStudyProgress = require("./logic/deleteStudyProgress");

module.exports = (config, services, models) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    return deleteById(models, req.params)
      .then((user) => {
        return deleteFootPrint(models, req.params)
          .then(() => {
            
            if (!user["profile_key"]) {
              res.status(200).json({ success: true });
            } else {
              console.log(user["profile_key"]);
              fileUpload
                .deleteProfilePicture(user.profile_key, services.s3, config)
                .then(() => {
                  fileUpload
                    .deleteUserDocuments(user.profile_key, services.s3, config)
                    .then(() => {
                      fileUpload.deleteUserAssignments(
                        user.profile_key,
                        services.s3,
                        config
                      );
                    });
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                  next(err);
                });
            }
          })
          .then(() => {
            return deleteDocuments(models, req.params).then(() => {
              return deleteAssignments(models, req.params).then(() => {
                return deleteQueries(models, req.params).then(() => {
                  return deleteStudyProgress(models, req.params)
                    .then((results) => {
                      res.status(200).json({ success: true });
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                      next(err);
                    });
                });
              });
            });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            next(err);
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        next(err);
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: That sounds more like a question for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: That's not a promise chain, that's a callback hell

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
module.exports = (config, services, models) => {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = await 
    deleteById(models, 
    req.params)
      
    await deleteFootPrint(models, 
    req.params)
         
   And so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

May you will get an idea how to covert the code from promise to async/await code.

```js
"use strict";

const deleteById = require("./logic/deleteById");
const deleteFootPrint = require("./logic/deleteFootPrint");
const fileUpload = require("../../helpers/fileUpload");
const deleteDocuments = require("./logic/deleteDocuments");
const deleteAssignments = require("./logic/deleteAssignments");
const deleteQueries = require("./logic/deleteQueries");
const deleteStudyProgress = require("./logic/deleteStudyProgress");

module.exports = async (config, services, models) => {
return async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let user = await deleteById(models, req.params);
        if (user) {
            await deleteFootPrint(models, req.params);
            if (!user["profile_key"]) {
                return res.status(200).json({ success: true });
            } else {
                console.log(user["profile_key"]);
                await fileUpload.deleteProfilePicture(user.profile_key, services.s3, config);
                await fileUpload.deleteUserDocuments(user.profile_key, services.s3, config);
                await fileUpload.deleteUserAssignments(user.profile_key, services.s3, config);
            }
        }
        await deleteDocuments(models, req.params);
        await deleteAssignments(models, req.params);
        await deleteQueries(models, req.params);
        let results = await deleteStudyProgress(models, req.params);
        if (results) {
            return res.status(200).json({ success: true });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
};
};
```